# Help with marble problem

Tags: functions

> In a box, there are red and blue marbles. If you take away one red marble,
>   1/4 of all marbles are red. If, on the other hand, you add a red one, 1/3 of all marbles are red. How many blue marbles are in the box?

If we say:

- x = Amount of red marbles
- y = Amount of blue marbles
- n = Total amount of marbles

Then, what I get from the statement above is:

- x + y = n
- (x - 1) = n/4
- (x + 1) = n/3

But I dont get any further from there.

I do **not** want the solution, but a hint would be helpful.

Source: http://monoid.mathematik.uni-mainz.de/monoid127.pdf (Page 21, Exercise 1163)

Comment: it's three equations in three unknowns...just eliminate one at a time.

Comment: Note:  your equations are not correct.  Well, $x+y=n$ is correct.  But the next should be $x-1=\frac {n-1}4$ and similarly for the third.

Comment: if you wanted a limited search chinese remainder theorem might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\color{red}{r}$ be the number of red marbles and $\color{blue}{b}$ be the number of blue marbles. If we remove a red marble ...
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\color{red}{r}-1}{\color{blue}{b}+\color{red}{r}-1} =\frac{1}{4} \\
\color{blue}{b}+3=3\color{red}{r}
\end{eqnarray*}
If we add a red marble ...
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\color{red}{r}+1}{\color{blue}{b}+\color{red}{r}+1} =\frac{1}{3} \\
2\color{red}{r}+2=\color{blue}{b} 
\end{eqnarray*}
So $ 2\color{red}{r}+5=\color{blue}{b}+3=3\color{red}{r}$ etc...

> $b=12$

Answer (score 0):

Guide:

$$x-1 = \frac{n-1}{4}$$

$$x+1 = \frac{n+1}{3}$$

Solve for $x$ and $n$. After which, solve for $y$.

Comment: Subtract first equation from second is a good way to make progress